# php curl loging into website for data proccesing

Tags: php, curl

Tryed this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://site/takelogin.php');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username=USER&password=PASS');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$store = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Everything starts in **login.php** but form goe's to **takelogin.php**, and if username and password correct it redirect's to **acc.php** For better understand posting part of **login.php** html side which i think important:

```
<form action="takelogin.php" id="signup" method="post">
<input id="username" name="username" type="text" maxlength="25" value="">
<input id="password" name="password" type="password" maxlength="60" value="">
<input name="commit" type="submit" value="Login">
<input type="hidden" name="returnto" value="/acc.php"
```

Even in browser url bar tryed enter: 
`http://site/takelogin.php?returnto=acc.php&username=USER&password=PASS`
No luck.

What i'm missing in mine curl script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want curl to follow php redirects you need to use this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

But you also have the "returnto" field in your form, which you don't use in your curl script. Do you need that variable, or is it optional?

Comment: Then the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION should suffice

Comment: It has to be `true` to tell curl to follow redirects. false disables the redirects and curl will stay put.

Comment: dear god how did I miss that?!

Comment: How about setting cookie name and value ? Because with wget it works:
wget -O test.txt --no-cookies --header "Cookie: login=HASH"  http://site/download.php?id=1

Answer (score 0):

If you need to provide credentials for basic authentication, make sure you add something like the following in your form receipt script.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
```

Comment: Pointless if the site is not using basic authentication. Setting this value will not magically make the user/pass work on a form-based login.

Answer (score 0):

Curl does not follow redirects by default, there's CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION for that.

With no access to this login system, at most we can say that perhaps the login script is checking for the submit button's value, so add `commit=Login` to your query values.